# How to use clearInterval() in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, clearinterval

I am trying to use setInterval in my Angular 4 app.

```
const inter = setInterval(() => {
  // logic resulting in exitCondition
  if(exitCondition) {
    clearInterval(inter);
  }
}, 1000);
```

This set up works fine in vanilla javascript, but `clearInterval()` does not seem to work in Angular. Upon doing some research I found an interval service for Angular 1.x :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Is there anything similar for Angular 4? Or is there a workaround to make clearInterval() work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can set like this,

```
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {

  }, 1000);
```

and clear like this,

```
if (this.interval) {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Would you mind explaining why it works like this when clearing it inside the interval doesn't?

Comment: because `this` doesn't refer to your original object in your callback when you invoke it that way. -- if you want `this` to work, you can declare your function as a lambda, like this: `private callback = () => { clearInterval(this.interval); };` -- you can call it from anywhere in your class just like a regular method (even make it public), and then `this` will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want in same method with some condition

```
var a = 1;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(a++)
      if(a > 30){
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the setInterval function starts after the user presses the key, there is a problem. If the user presses the key more than once, the following happens:

- setInterval1 -> start
- setInterval2 -> start

And when the stop button is pressed:

- setInterval2 -> stop

For this reason, the setInterval1 process never stops. For this, we need to declare a boolean value variable. It will get the value "true" when the key is pressed and check it with "if" at the beginning of the function.